# Chat support for ASCII printable characters and Unicode

Tags: feature-request, chat, localization, unicode

Currently parts of the chat engine ignore Unicode characters and punctuation, so if someone's name consists of non-Latin characters it's impossible to ping them.

Presumably there are Stack Exchange plans to improve support for internationalisation(?)  If there are, could this be put on the todo list?

Comment: After seeing your gravatar, I keep reading this question as `unicorn usernames`... :-)

Comment: It's not only Unicode characters. My username there is `F'x` (which is ASCII only) and I can't be pinged either…

Comment: @FX, did you have that user name on the sites too? (And if so: did notification fail then as well?)